# Apache wildcard cert with virtual host subdomain

Tags: ssl, https, apache2, lets-encrypt

I have been stuck trying to get my site to work with SSL and a subdomain for a few days now. Have been googling endlessly to no avail.

I have a webserver setup on AWS EC2 instance running amazon Linux 2 with apache (httpd).

I currently have a letsencrypt wildcard certificate on my server.

Got a Virtual host file below enabled (/etc/httpd/sites-enabled):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
    ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/example.com/requests.log combined
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain.example.com
    ErrorLog /var/www/subdomain.example.com/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/subdomain.example.com/requests.log combined
    Redirect permanent / https://subdomain.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
    ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/example.com/requests.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName subdomain.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain.example.com
    ErrorLog /var/www/subdomain.example.com/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/subdomain.example.com/requests.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

If I go to https://example.com I get a certificate error

But if I go to https://subdomain.example.com it works fine showing the correct letsencrypt certificate.

I don't understand why the certificate is not working for both domain and subdomain.

Can someone please help me see what the issue might be?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure main domain is using vhost config and not the default config of Apache?

Comment: I would think vhost would be working, else wouldn't the default config just point my site to /var/www/html? I can confirm it is definitely opening my site from the files located in /var/www/example.com folder.

Comment: BTW, are you intentionally making your log files public? In the current configuration you have `ErrorLog` and `CustomLog` both placed under the `DocumentRoot`! Although it doesn't answer your question, it's worth to note.

Comment: Oops, yeah silly mistake. I will have to move them.

Answer (score 0):

Wildcard certificates work only on one level of domains. If you have `host1.domain.tld` and `host2.domain.tld` certificate for `*.domain.tld` will work. But the same certificate will not work for `host2.domain.domain.tld` nor for `domain.tld` hosts. for first host you need certificate like `*.domain.domain.tld` for second `*.tld`

What you can do is to use `subdomain.domain.tld` (this is actually host, not domain) as CN in to the certificate and `domain.tld` as alternative name (or whatever was named)

Comment: yes, but my situation I only need host2.domain.tl to work, not host2.domain.domain.tld.

Comment: @BruH, you CAN'T use the same wildcard certificate for host.domain.tld and domain.tld`

Comment: This is easy to test as it should match the `ServerAlias www.example.com`. It's common for wildcard certificates to list the `example.com` in *Subject Alternative Name*s, circumventing this [RFC 2595, 2.4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2595#section-2.4) limitation: "A `*` wildcard character MAY be used as the left-most name component in the certificate. For example, `*.example.com` would  match `a.example.com`, `foo.example.com`, etc. but would not match `example.com`."

Answer (score 0):

had a default certificate file overriding my own due to config in the ssl.conf file (/etc/httpd/conf.d/)

Replaced these 2 lines with my own certificate files:
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key

All working now. Thanks guys.

Comment: At the end the problem was with certificates